# Reference to the Existence and Uniqueness of the PDE system

Tags: differential-equations, elliptic-pde, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I've the following Problem on systems of Partial Differential Equations. I have "$ N $" Physical variables. and Finally I  form the equation on a bounded domain having  regular boundary in $R^d$ ($d=2$ generally)

$\mbox{div}(W_i)=f_i$,  $i=1\cdots N$

$W_i =\displaystyle \sum_{i, j=1}^NA_{ij} \cdot\nabla P_j$ with summation indices $j=1\cdots N$
where each $A_{ij}$ is $2\times 2$ non-constant matrix  and N unknowns $P_1...P_N$. For $N=1$ based on existing theory of elliptic PDE one can ascertain existence and uniqueness by looking at coefficient matrix.But can someone kindly give any reference to the existence and uniqueness of these  kind of problems.And moreover if not then any reference\idea  whether existing DN-elliptic systems can be modified to tackle these kind of problems..??

regards
ram

Comment: You should $\TeX$ the equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good keyword here is *strongly elliptic systems*. There is an original paper by Nirenberg. Also have a look at MacLean's book *Strongly elliptic systems and boundary integral operators*. Folland's *Introduction to PDE* has a good treatment too.

Comment: Thanks a lot.And moreover if the A_ij are not constants then is there any way to decouple the system into N PDEs of one variable...??For example by any basis transformation or something like that..!!!!!